# i3 screen tearing

Tags: tearing, i3-wm

Ok so I have some pretty bad screen tearing, like a very brief white flash when I mod1+enter to open a new terminal instance (I don't have the problem when I change workspace)

I've already tried :

- changing terminal emulator (terminator, xterm, urxvt)
- using compton, adding *exec --no-startup-id compton --backend glx --vsync opengl-swc* in .i3/config based on comments in other formus

Comment: what makes you think "screen tearing" manifests as  a white flash??

Comment: dunno, I just observe that when I close or open terminal, the screen kind of tears up with white pixels

Comment: Does it affect only terminal windows? Is it the whole screen or just the current or new window? Also, can you please check, whether you have a line starting with `client.background` in your i3 configuration?

Comment: does it happen on black backgrounds? It could be your GPU driver

Comment: I have solved my screen tearing by installing and configuring `compton` window compositor alongside the `i3`. Just something to consider.